# How to run an RMarkdown multiple times given an external table with multiple sets of input parameters?

Tags: r, markdown

I have one RMarkdown file that is the format for generating multiple reports (one per site). Currently,  I would either edit the inputs at the top of my markdown with the details for a given site, then run the report. Then I would repeat this 15x.

Instead, I would like to write a separate R script that renders the RMarkdown script and produces separate htmls for each site, where the site inputs are read in via an an external table.
Any suggestions? Would the best solution involve a loop to say to generate it for each row in the Excel, or something else? Code suggestions highly appreciated!

Past Markdown:

```
# Set these parameters only once

start_date <- "2020-04-01"
end_date   <- "2022-03-31"
site_acr <- "siteA"
site_code <- 1
```

Example Excel table to be read into the R script

```
site_code site_Acr site_name start_date end_date
1         siteA   siteAfull  2020-01-01  2022-12-31
2         siteB   siteBfull  2019-01-01  2021-12-31
3         siteC   siteCfull  2020-07-01  2022-06-31
```

EDIT: I turned my Markdown into a parameterized report via YAML reader, which works for individual sites:

```
title: "**Quality Dashboard: `r params$site_full`**"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
params:
  site_acr: siteA
  site_full: siteAfull
  site_code: 1
  start_date: 2020-04-01
  end_date:   2022-03-31
```

Instead of multiple manual lines of `rmarkdown::render()`, rmarkdown::render()`etc... I'm now trying to follow this example, where I expect the paramaters from my`inputs` file to override those in the YAML: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/parameterized-reports.html

```
inputs <- structure(list(site_code = c(1, 2, 3), 
                    site_acr = c("siteA", "siteB", "siteC"),
                    site_name = c("siteAfull  ", "siteBfull",  "siteCfull"), 
                    start_date = structure(c(1588291200,  1588291200, 1572566400), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
                    end_date = structure(c(1651276800, 1651276800, 1635638400  ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), 
               class = c("tbl_df",  "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))

render_one <- function(site_code, site_acr , site_full, start_date, end_date ) {
  # assuming the output format of input.Rmd is html
  rmarkdown::render(
    'X:/filepath/Quality Dash.Rmd',
    output_file = paste0(site_acr, '.html'),    # Name is file by site
    params = list(site_code  = site_code, 
                  site_acr   = site_acr,
                  site_full  = site_full,
                  start_date = start_date,
                  end_date   = end_date   ),
    envir = parent.frame()
  )
}

# Not working: 
  
  for (site in inputs$site_acr) {
      render_one(site_code, site_acr , site_full, start_date, end_date )
  }
# Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 64
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to use parameterized markdown reports: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/parameterized-reports.html. You'll need to define your variables as proper document parameters. You then call `rmarkdown::render` multiple times with whatever parameter values you want.

Comment: @MrFlick Thanks! I updated my question to involve params. Any suggestions ?

Comment: You are not passing in a single row of data at a time. One way to do that might be `for (row in 1:nrow(inputs)) {with(inputs[, row], render_one(site_code, site_acr , site_full, start_date, end_date ))}`

Comment: Thank you but that is giving `Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 64`

Comment: Oh. I put the index in the wrong place. It should have been `for (row in 1:nrow(inputs)) {with(inputs[row,], render_one(site_code, site_acr , site_full, start_date, end_date ))}`

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work! Note that the first 2 times I ran this, it worked (produced reports) for the first 2 but threw an error about characters as dates only for the third site. The third time I ran it, the error went away and all 3 three reports were generated.

```
library(readxl)
inputs <- read_excel("X:/DashboardInputs.xlsx")

# Create a report for each row in the inputs table
for (i in seq_along(inputs$site_code)) {
  rmarkdown::render("X:/TemplateMarkdown.Rmd", 
                    output_dir = "S:/Dashboards" ,
                    output_file = sprintf( inputs$site_acr[i]),
                    params = list(
                      site_code  = inputs$site_code[i], 
                      site_acr   = inputs$site_acr[i], 
                      site_full  = inputs$site_full[i] ,
                      start_date = inputs$start_date[i],
                      end_date   = inputs$end_date[i]  ))
}
```